# How to extend task in all scopes (even currently undefined)?

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-plugin

I am writing a plugin that adds sets to the `compile` task.

```
package myplugin

import sbt._
import Keys._

object MyPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  object autoImport {}

  override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
    compile <<= compile.andFinally {
      println("foo")
    }
  )

}
```

But when I use it in a project, I see

```
Reference to undefined setting:
  *:compile from *:compile ((myplugin.MyPlugin) MyPlugin.scala:10)
     Did you mean compile:compile ?
```

This will be useful in likely whatever context compiler is defined in (`Compile`, `Test`, etc.).

Changing `compile` to `(compile in Compile)` fixes the problem.

But explicitly listing the contexts will omit some, like `ScctTest` (that's from the SCCT plugin, for code coverage).

Is there a way that I can define this operation for all contexts have a compile? Or am I trying to do something that goes against best practices?

Comment: Google for "sbt derived setting". That's what you're looking for.